# Should we use full names or last names in name tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should name tags (for example, directors or actors) be of the form [surname] (for well-known enough, unambiguous names, such as Tarantino), or [firstname-surname]?

I propose full name tags.

Further, should we have tag synonyms to map the most famous name to the full name? For example, [tarantino] -> [quentin-tarantino].

I propose we do map them, unless the surname is ambiguous and used by many people.

This has been discussed on [meta.Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/should-we-use-full-names-or-last-names-in-author-tags) and [SF&F](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/naming-convention-for-tags), where the general consensus was for the longer name.

(And of course, we should map misspellings of names as synonyms: [stephen-spielberg] -> [steven-spielberg].)

Answer (score 11):

Use full name tags, it looks more professional.

If someone types the last name, the tag suggestions will pop the full name up anyway. Note that it doesn't work in reverse: if only the full name tag exists and someone starts typing the first name, they won't notice the existing tag.

There's no need to create synonyms for misspellings until they arise naturally.

Answer (score 7):

I think that it is good to use the full name to remove ambiguity.  Yes there are some very well known directors that you could easily know from their last name: Spielberg, Hitchcock, Tarantino etc - but it does no harm to use synonyms to map these to full names.

Although the number of questions and tags is relatively small now, we might start to have conflicts if we go for surname only, e.g. Cameron Crowe & Russel Crowe.

Comment: Or Will Farrel and Collin Farrel, John and Joan Cusack, Jake and Maggie Gylanhal, etc.